# Website tracking list of companies delisted on NYSE exchange

Tags: equities, market-data

I want to find the list of comapanies delisted on NYSE exchange and the companies which will be delisted, is there any website which tracks it on a real time basis?

Answer (score 2):

You can find active delisting on the [NYSE website](https://www.nyse.com/regulation/delistings). As for the list of delisted companies, generally what you are looking for is the [Form 25](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/sec-form-25.asp)

> A notification given to the SEC by a national securities exchange telling of the removal from listing on that exchange and registration of matured, redeemed or retired corporate securities. SEC Form 25 is required by Rule 12d2-2 of the Securities Exchange Act of 1934. A security is considered to be delisted 10 days after the filing of Form 25 with the SEC.

You can get the list of the most recent filings from [EDGAR](https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?company=&CIK=&type=25-NSE&owner=include&count=100&action=getcurrent)